# Getting control value when switching a view as part of a multiview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button id="display_button" runat="server" Text="Display" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> &nbsp;
<asp:Button id="edit_button" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Button2_Click" /> &nbsp; 
<asp:Button id="save_button" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button3_Click" Visible="false" /> &nbsp; 

<asp:MultiView id="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View id="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:FormView id="view_program" runat="server"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("status").ToString().Trim() %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View id="View2" runat="server">
        <asp:FormView id="edit_program" runat="server"> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList id="p_status" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

and the following functions attached to the buttons in the code-behind page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
    save_button.Visible = false;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
    save_button.Visible = true;
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList p_status = edit_program.FindControl("p_status") as DropDownList;
    var status = p_status.SelectedValue;
    Label1.Text = status;
    //save_button.Visible = false;
    //MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
}
```

The idea being, that there are two views, the first displays the information, if the user wants to edit the information, they click button 2 which changes the view to the edit mode, which has the controls (drop downs, text fields, etc). It also makes the 'save' button appear.

What I am trying to make happen is, when the save button is clicked, it will grab all of the values from the various fields, update the object and then update the database. Then it would flip back to view1 with the updated info.

Problem is, as you can see in `void Button3_Click`, I try grab the values from the control, p_status, but it only gets the original value. example, the menu has three values, 'Green', 'Yellow', and 'Red'. Green is the default value and is selected when view2 is displayed. However, if I select Yellow or Red, and click save, rather than the label being updated to display one of those two values, it always displays Green.

Any ideas?

edit: page load function per request below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    Person myPerson = new Person(userid);
    TestProgram myProgram = new TestProgram(id);

    List<TestProgram> program = new List<TestProgram> { myProgram };

    view_program.DataSource = program;
    view_program.DataBind();
    edit_program.DataSource = program;
    edit_program.DataBind();


    DropDownList p_status = edit_program.FindControl("p_status") as DropDownList;
    p_status.Items.Add(new ListItem("Green", "Green"));
    p_status.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yellow", "Yellow"));
    p_status.Items.Add(new ListItem("Red", "Red"));
    //myProgram.Status = "Red";
    p_status.SelectedValue = myProgram.Status;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Response.Write(ex);
    Label1.Text = ex.ToString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show page_load and (if you have one) page_init. Depending on how/when you are databinding the values of p_status maybe getting reset before the button3_click is invoked.

Comment: I edited it into the OP.

Comment: so, what is the reason for the `<itemTemplate>?`

Answer (score 0):

> Whoops...missed a little someting.. my
> bad

when asp.net is not behaving as expected this is your best friend: [MSDN: ASP.NET PAGE LIFECYLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

**Upon Further Review...**

there are a couple of problems here. your drop down list control with an id of "p_status" is contained inside a multiview *(I forgot about what that meant...)* you need to move the code to populate p_status into pre-render after checking to see if Multiveiw1.ActiveView =  View2. Since it will always be a post back you need to bind values late in the page cycle

Comment: when i do that, the menu never has any options added to it (my theory being that clicking the button to change the view state counts as a postback)

Comment: are you disabling viewstate for the control? for a quick fix move those lines to pre_render.

Comment: no, everything i have is presented here. how would i do that?

Comment: @Josh, I have revised my answer. I will be away for a while, but will check back to see if you have an answer later.

Comment: Well, I added `if (MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex == '1')` around the code that populates the field, but it still doesn't seem to work. it seems like it's always 'behind', i.e. when I click it the first time, the menu is not populated, but if i click button 2 again it is.

also, isn't the page_load function already part of pre-render? is it maybe a page_init thing that I don't understand the difference on?

Comment: @Josh. Looking at the `<itemTemplate>` I see your `list<TestProgram>` program, and it is a datasource, but I don't see a data repeater or other data control that is being bound. (where are the view_program or edit_program controls that should support `<itemTemplate>`?). If they are outside the scope of what you have shown, by putting the multview inside the repeater but outside the item template could be disrupting the order of operations on your page.  Step back from the page you have and start by building a page with multiview, some buttons and a drop down, etc.

Comment: sorry, the item template is a leftover from when i had a repeater in there. i removed the repeater and changed it to a formview since a repeater was not neccesary (only dealing with one set of data on this page) 

i had removed the itemtemplate, but it broke the page, so i figured it was a neccesary part of formview. is that incorrect?

Comment: i see them use it like that here http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-the-formview-s-templates-cs

also, to answer your question, the edit_program and view_program controls are the formviews. you can see them above, wrapping the itemtemplates.